# Use historycalRecords as default model in view class

Tags: python, django

I am using `HistorycalRecords` as table member

```
from simple_history.models import HistoricalRecords
class Delivery(BaseModel):
    history = HistoricalRecords(
        excluded_fields=['created_by', 'updated_by', 'updated_at'])
```

It create another table automatically named such as `myapp_historicaldelivery`

Now I want to use historical table itself as default model of view.

Because I would like to show the list of changed points.

```
class ActionLogListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListSearchView):
    template_name = "message_logs/action_log.html"
    form_class = ActionLogSearchForm
    model = Delivery.history // want to set here.
```

However it shows error, maybe because Delivery.history is not model.

```
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

HistorycalModel source code is here

https://github.com/jazzband/django-simple-history/blob/master/simple_history/models.py

How can I treat history as model class to show the list in view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Model.history.model` to access the history model for use in the generic views

```
class ActionLogListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListSearchView):
    template_name = "message_logs/action_log.html"
    form_class = ActionLogSearchForm
    model = Delivery.history.model
```